# NestJSX get parameter from CrudRequest object

Tags: nestjs, crud

I want to overrride the following route which was generated by nestjsx:

```
GET /offer-event-matchings/{id}
```

To get the id from the CrudRequest I wrote the following code.

```
  @Override()
  getOne(@ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest): Promise<GetUserDto> {
    const id = req.parsed.search.$and[1]['id']['$eq'];
    return this.service.getOfferEventMatching(id);
  }
```

It works but I think and hope there is a better and more beautiful way to get the id from the CrudRequest object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom of the section [Routes Override](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#routes-override) in the docs mentions you can use the typical decorators as well, so the easiest would be to use `Param`:

```js
getOne(
  @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
  @Param('id') id: string
): Promise<GetUserDto> {
  // code here
}
```